# Hibernate and Spring DataSourceTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I'm trying to work with Hibernate and Spring DataSourceTransactionManager to handle commit and rollback functions, but probably I dind't get something.

Before using Spring DataSourceTransactionManager, this was one of my DAO class

```
  package com.springgestioneerrori.DAO;

  public class UtenteDAO extends DAOBase{   

       public void salvaUtente(Utente utenteIn) throws DAOException{ 

            Session session = getHibernateSession(); //from this method  I get Hibernate SessionFactory
              try{   
                  session.beginTransaction();             
                  session.saveOrUpdate(Object); 
                  session.getTransaction().commit();    
                  }
              catch(Exception e){
                  session.getTransaction().rollback()
              }
        }
}
```

This is the class that give me the sessionFactory

```
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

            private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
                try {
                    // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                    return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();  
                }
                catch (Throwable ex) {
                              System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
                }
            }

            public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
                return sessionFactory;
            }

            public static void shutdown() {             
                getSessionFactory().close();
            }

public Session getHibernateSession (){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    return session;
}
```

Now i'm trying to use DataSourceTransactionManager in a declarative way. Following some examples on the internet I wrote this:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />        

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="salvaUtente"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="userDaoTxPointcut" expression="execution(* com.springgestioneerrori.DAO.UtenteDAO.salvaUtente(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userDaoTxPointcut" />
</aop:config>
```

Now, what should I write inside the method salvaUtente() to perform many inserts, for example like these

```
  session.saveOrUpdate(User); 
  session.saveOrUpdate(UserCredentials); 
  session.saveOrUpdate(UserOtherDetails);
```

and making Spring handle commint and rollback?

Comment: what is the unit work ? All inserts is a unit of work or insert number 3 should be happen irrespective of other inserts

Comment: All the inserts are bound to each others, if one insert fails other inserts must have no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you are using the wrong  transaction manager. The `DataSourceTransactionManager` isn't for Hibernate but for plain JDBC. If you are using plain Hibernate use the `HibernateTransactionManager`. (Assuming that you are using Hibernate 4 here!).

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Now I would also suggest to use `@Transactional` instead of a `<tx:advice />` and `<aop:config />` block. Makes your configuration easier. Simply remove the 2 mentioned blocks and replace with `<tx:annotation-driven />`.

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Now your code is wrong as you are starting transactions yourself. Annotate your method with `@Transactional` (after adding the thing above) and remove your transaction handling code.

```
@Transactional
public void salvaUtente(Utente utenteIn) throws DAOException{ 
    Session session = getHibernateSession(); //from this method  I get Hibernate SessionFactory
    session.saveOrUpdate(Object); 
}
```

Now I don't know what your `getHibenateSession` method does but make sure you don't use `openSession` on the `SessionFactory` to obtain a session. Use `getCurrentSession` instead.

```
protected Session getHibernateSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

Your current `BaseDAO` class is flawed. Delete your `buildSessionFactory` and remove the `static final`. Let Spring configure and inject the `SessionFactory`.

```
public abstract class BaseDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getHibernateSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

In your configuration add the configuration for the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    ... Other Hibernate Properties
</bean>
```

That is basically all that is needed. This is also all explained in detail in [the Spring Reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate). I strongly suggest a read.

Comment: I edited my post and added the class that give me  the sessionFactory

Comment: If io try to use getCurrentSession instead of openSessione a get No CurrentSessionContext configured!

Comment: Then your configuration is wrong (see my modified answer) and please read the link that is now included in it. The reference guide explains in detail how to set things up with hibernate. I strongly suggest a read.

Comment: Thank you man. I followed your example and read the link, but I still miss one step. Now I get the error Unknown entity on my persisent object, annotated as @Entity, after calling the method saveOrUpdate(). Probably I have to map that class inside the sessioneFactory  or transactionManager bean, but I can't find an example on that link.

Comment: Maybe i got it. I replaced LocalSessionFactoryBean with AnnotationSessionFactoryBea that extends LocalSessionFactoryBean. This way i can use the annotatedClasses property. So far it seems to work. Thank you very much for your valuable help.

Comment: I assumed yo used hibernate 4 (this was also part of the answer).

Comment: @M.Deinum what's the option if I use Hibernate 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
@Transaction(rollbackFor = {if you need to rollback on certain checked exception})
salvaUtente()
```

The transaction is only roll backed for unchecked exception until mentioned otherwise.

if there is an exception at any point salvaUtente in the transaction will be roll backed else the transaction will be committed once the method is existed

Comment: I still miss a step. What should I write insde salveUtente() to manage the 3 insert session.saveOrUpdate(User);    session.saveOrUpdate(UserCredentials); 
  session.saveOrUpdate(UserOtherDetails);

Answer (score 0):

HibernateTransactionManager can also manage the transactions on the DataSource. We need to inject the DataSource in the HibernateTransactionManager and it should work for both, Hibernate and plain old SQL.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager>
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Hope this works for you.

(*I know this is pretty late, but may help someone landing to this post*)